# Trying to display the contents of a folder including the size, date modified, and length

Tags: powershell

This script is working so far, but I need the size to be in KB. It works as well, but when I call for a list of files it just outputs the KB size below the list, instead of within the list of itself.

```
$fileList = Get-ChildItem "E:\"
foreach($file in $fileList) {
    ls $file | select -Property fullName, LastWriteTime, length
}
foreach($file in $fileList) {
    Write-Host((Get-Item $file).length/1KB) | Sort-Object fullName, LastWriteTime, length
}
```

I want to see how I can get the KB size to populate the list under length, instead of the default file size being displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `Select-Object` to get only the properties you want:

```
Get-ChildItem "E:\" | Select-Object fullName,LastWriteTime,Length
```

```
FullName                      LastWriteTime       Length
--------                      -------------       ------
C:\folder\cluster_totals.xlsx 14/12/2017 15:11:40  9382
C:\folder\IAG.xlsx            23/11/2017 11:05:12 13054
C:\folder\Offline.xml         30/10/2017 16:14:24 21503
```

And then use [Calculated Properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) to change the formatting of the `Length` property into KB.

```
Get-ChildItem "E:\" | Select-Object fullName,LastWriteTime,@{Name="KB";Expression={"{0:N0}" -f ($_.Length / 1KB)}}
```

Which will give you something like this:

```
FullName                      LastWriteTime       KBytes
--------                      -------------       ------
C:\folder\cluster_totals.xlsx 14/12/2017 15:11:40 9
C:\folder\IAG.xlsx            23/11/2017 11:05:12 13
C:\folder\Offline.xml         30/10/2017 16:14:24 21
```